# Finding the Generalized Eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given is the matrix,

\begin{bmatrix}0&0&-2&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\1&1&2&0&0\\-1&-1&-2&-1&-2\\1&1&2&1&2\\\end{bmatrix}

Find the generalized eigenspace for the eigenvalue λ = 0.

---

I have found two solutions for the eigenvector for the eigenvalue 0.

$$ λ_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\\0\\0\\\end{bmatrix}    
λ_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\-2\\1\\\end{bmatrix}$$

The eigenvalue 0 has an algebraic multiplicity of 2. See the characteristic polynomial $$λ^2(1-λ)^3$$

I find the same vectors $$λ_1, λ_2$$ also for the generalized eigenvector.

Are these steps correct? And what is the generalized eigenspace? Are my vectors the bases of the space?

Thanks.

Edit: Sorry, my bad the question asks for generalized eigenspace not for eigenvector.

Comment: Seems that you have to find the generalized eigenvector for $\lambda=1$.

Comment: The question asks for λ = 0

Comment: But for $\lambda=0$, we have no generalized eigenvector, because there are $2$ linear independent vectors solving $Ax=0$

Comment: @AriNubar as Peter said, there must be a mistake in the question itself or in the way that you copied it.

Comment: $$S=\pmatrix{-1&0&0&-2&4\\1&0&0&1&-2\\0&0&0&1&-1\\0&-2&-1&0&0\\0&1&1&0&0}$$

Comment: $S^{-1}AS$ with $A$ the above matrix, has Jordan-normal-form. The last two columns are the generalized eigenvectors to $\lambda=1$.

Comment: I cannot remember how to find the second generalized eigenvector. The first solves $(A-I)^2x=0$. Solving $(A-I)^3x=0$, I got $(0/0/1/0/0)$, but this leads to a wrong matrix (It contains a $2$ instead of a $0$ at position $3/5$

Comment: Sorry all, my bad, the question asks for the generalized eigenspace not for the generalized eigenvector